# Combine two components in one template override

Tags: template-override, com-content

Basically, I want to display the "Add to Cart" block of j2store component in a particular position of my com_content template override.
Any idea how can I do that? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Unless the code for the "Add to Cart" button is done through JLayouts or is available in some form of short code format, then you going to have to write a Template Override for the article view, import the component API and other snippets, which won't be an easy task

Comment: Ah it's too bad. Thanks for the comment anyway @Lodder

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to create a module, in this case "Add to cart" and then include it in the article with {loadmodule ....} syntaxis.

PD: not my favourite solution, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but j2store has already workaround if you want to move the add to cart button inside the article body (by using {j2store} short tag). What I tried to achieve is to place the add to cart button outside the article body area, using com_content template override.